# refactoring repetitive sass to modify based on immediate parent's class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

tldr: how to avoid repetition of ".well" selector in below example.

I am using bootstrap and sass to display a "well" div with a shape and with a gradient fill. This may not be a proper use of wells and I'd welcome other suggestions as to how to draw circular/rectangular divs with X% shaded (ideally where X is any integer. [0, 100]) but, for now, I am most interested in whether it's possible in SASS to get rid of the repetition of ".well". I tried using "&" but it would reverse .some_container too and I only wanted to reverse the immediate .inner_container parent to apply there (e.g. .inner_container.round). [There is one outer_container and multiple inner_containers. Each inner_container has one well.]

```
.outer_container {
  .inner_container {
    &.round .well {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    &.barely_filled .well {
      @include gradient-horizontal(sienna, $well-bg, 0%, 25%);
    }

    &.half_filled .well {
      @include gradient-horizontal(sienna, $well-bg, 0%, 50%);
    }

    &.fairly_filled .well {
      @include gradient-horizontal(sienna, $well-bg, 0%, 75%);
    }

    &.mostly_filled .well {
      background-color: sienna;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If the answer is significantly more verbose than what you currently have, are you still interested in an answer?  Also, please make sure that *everything* to get this to compile is provided.  It is very annoying to have to initialize variables, etc. (and quite often not worth the effort)

Comment: "significantly" more verbose? Probably not. I'm just new to CSS/SASS and the way I wrote it feels wrong. Maybe if the correct/idiomatic way of achieving what I'm trying to accomplish is more verbose but still better for good reason?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing.  The shortest selector to get to the specified element is always the best selector (eg. `tr td` vs `td`).  If you're nesting for structural reasons rather than because it is necessary for the selector, you're doing it for the wrong reason.

Answer (score 0):

The most terse way to write it would be like this:

```
@mixin well($sel) {
  &#{$sel} .well {
    @content;
  }
}

.outer_container {
  .inner_container {
    @include well('.round') {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    @include well('.barely_filled') {
      test: 1;
    }

    @include well('.half_filled') {
      test: 2;
    }

    @include well('.fairly_filled') {
      test: 3;
    }

    @include well('.mostly_filled') {
      background-color: sienna;
    }
  }
}
```

However, in addition to being more verbose, I feel that this decreases readability over what you currently have.